# Partition a large scale HDF5 dataset into sub-files

Tags: matlab, filesystems, dataset, hdfs, hdf5

I have a pretty large HDF5 dataset  which is of size [1 12672 1 228020] following the format:[height width channel N]. This file occupies about 22G on hard disk.

I want to partition this file in to smaller parts, say 2G files.

`h5repart` has been tried out but it does not work well, because I'm not able to display partitioned files in MATLAB using h5disp('...').

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be for you to use the 'chunk' capability of the HDF5 format.

Using the MATLAB [low-level HDF5 functions](http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/exporting-to-hierarchical-data-format-hdf5-files.html#bub60bt) you should be able to read the chunks you require.